# Why is the question about risks for working for a consultancy closed as opinion based?

Tags: discussion

I have asked [a question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15121/what-are-the-common-risks-when-working-for-an-it-consultancy) about working for a consultancy.

There are certain consultancy firms which employ their consultants at client location as contractors. I believe there are certain risks and disadvantages to this approach that the candidate should be aware of and plan to mitigate. I strongly believe the answers and this question are not opinion based. There are certain facts also.

For example, consultancies generally work on corp to corp contracts. They charge client more and they pay less after their margins. So your expectations from the client is more than what you get paid. If you are an immigrant worker they hold your VISA and hence it has its own risks.

These are certain risks that I am aware of. I believe the above question is not opinion based. People who believe it is opinion based, can you please explain why and how? If you agree with me, please vote to reopen the question.

Comment: FWIW, I'm pretty sure my vote was for "too broad".

Comment: Mine might also have been for "too broad" too, although it's also primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @BVR - It appears that my response came after an edit to the question. Did it help?

Comment: @MeredithPoor: Yes it helps. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 5):

When you originally [asked in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/conversation/discussion-between-bvr-and-jmac), I pointed you to this question:

[What is the difference between freelancer and contractor?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/what-is-the-difference-between-freelancer-and-contractor)

This question was upvoted and had useful answers, so I thought that asking a similar question about switching from full-time salaried employee to contractor would be good (since we amazingly don't seem to have one).

Instead it looked like you were asking, *"I heard that consultants aren't great to work for, what do you think?"* The question changed from what I anticipated was going to be one describing the difference in roles/responsibilities, to one polling for opinion.

That's why I voted to close as *primarily opinion-based*.

Comment: I didn't understand. Did you voted to close because it is not in the format what you anticipated? Or the question looks like opinion based. If the question looks like Opinion based, which part sounds like Opinion based?

Comment: @BVR, I thought your question would be on topic because I thought it would match an existing non-closed question. I voted to close as *primarily opinion-based* because you asked a different question that was primarily opinion-based. The reason for mentioning what was said in chat was to try to explain any disconnect you may have felt when I said one thing in chat, and did another.

Comment: This was further discussed [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/conversation/clarification-to-bvr-by-jmac)